# Soft limit vs hard limit

Tags: linux, ulimit, resources

I ran into a problem of :

```
fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I know that `nproc` is the problem
Some suggested to increase the soft limit of `nproc` while other suggested the hard limit.

Which should I increase?
Isn't the soft limit is there just to warn the user and the hard limit is the one that really limits eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually other way around.

The soft limit's value(s) is actually implemented i.e. in use, you can increase the limit upto the relevant hard limit's value(s) (assuming you are not super user or do not have `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability).

Comment: So the hard limit is just a limit of the soft limit for regular users?

Comment: @LironCohen You can think that way for understanding.

Comment: So what happens if only the hard limit specified?

Answer (score 2):

Think of the hard and the soft limits as mandatory and discretionary limits, resp. The hard limit is imposed by the system (through suitable configuration, e.g. `limits.conf(5)`) and can be increased only by the superuser (i.e. root), while the user can gauge soft limits at his discretion within the range of the according hard limits.

From the `getrlimits(2)` manual page:

> The soft limit is the value that the kernel enforces for the corresponding resource.  The hard limit acts as a ceiling for the soft limit: an unprivileged  process  may  set only its soft limit to a value in the range from 0 up to the hard limit, and (irreversibly) lower its hard limit.

Thus, if you hit a resource limit, then check whether you can increase the according soft limit; if not, then the hard limit needs to be increased.

**Response to Comment**

There is no such thing as *only the hard limit*. Limits are set by `setrlimit(2)`, which refers to `struct rlimit`. This in turn has members for soft and hard limit (`rlim_cur` and `rlim_max`, resp.). If a soft limit is not explicitly defined, then it defaults to some value; most likely the according hard limit, but this is up to the process that sets the limits. (`setrlimits(2)` rejects `rlim_cur` exceeding `rlim_max`, so `RLIM_INFINITY` is typically *not* a valid default for `rlim_cur`.)

Comment: What happens if only the hard limit specified?

Comment: @LironCohen see my edit